# Advanced sumproduct

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I'm trying to condense a column of formulas into an advanced sum product which would effectively use a CountIf based on a criteria—but I'm having trouble putting the formula together.

How do you count the number of unique values using a sumproduct? 
The picture below has column C, I want to condense the sum of column C (`11`) into a single formula without using this helper column.  The current formula is showing in the formula bar.

[image: Column trying to condence]

Comment: So you want `11` with one formula without the helper column C?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. I'll update the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 4):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A:A,INDEX(A:A,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(B2:B36="Y",ROW(B2:B36)*{1,1})))))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.

The INDEX basically builds an array of the values in column A where the corresponding value in B is `Y`.  This array is then passed to the COUNTIFS.

The SUM wrapper causes the COUNTIF to iterate through the array provided by the INDEX and sum each result.

[image]

Comment: This is perfect and the explanation is clear—thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use this "array formula"

`=SUM(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A36,IF(B2:B36="Y",A2:A36),0))+0)`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

I don't know if it's possible for a "Y" to be against the same ID more than once - if so then this version would avoid any double counting